# How to get width, height and depth of selected elements in Revit using C#

Tags: c#, revit

How to get the width, height and depth of selected elements in Revit using C#.
Please help me and share the code.
Thanks
Philip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to simply query the selected element for its bounding box using the [`BoundingBox` property](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018/def2f9f2-b23a-bcea-43a3-e6de41b014c8.htm).

Here is an example of using it for [Determining Model Extents via Wall Bounding Box](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/05/filterrule-use-and-retrieving-exterior-walls.html#7).